# Eloquent relationship to point to records in the same table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have an employee table as follows:

- id
- name
- supervisor

This has all the employees in it, and is the only table i have

The `supervisor` field, holds the `id` of the `supervisor`, which is saved in the same table as an `employee`.

I have a table that prints out the list of all the `employees`, and their `supervisors`.

Right now, it only prints the `id` of the supervisor. I am trying to translate that `id`, to the name of the `supervisor`. So I decided to use 'belongsTo()' & 'hasMany()' in the same model.

I have tried a variety of models and controller codes, but every time a different error popsup. I think my controller side is the issue.

**Employee Model**

```php
//
public function employee(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Employee', 'id');
}

public function manager(){
    return $this->hasMany('Employee', 'id');
}
```

**EmployeeController**

```php
$employees = Employee::all();
return view('employee/index')->with('employees', $employees, $employees->manager);
```

**index**

```php
<td>
   {{$employee->$manager->name}}
</td>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `$manager`. Remove the `$` so it looks like `$employee->manager->name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I'm asumming that `supervisor` is the employee id of the supervisor.

---

There's something wrong with your relationships, the second parameter of the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` methods needs to be the foreign key of the related model (in this case, the same model, but the key that references the parent object, like `supervisor`). Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) regarding this subject:

> Like the hasOne method, you may also override the foreign and local keys by passing additional arguments to the hasMany method:
>
> ```php
> return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key');
>
> return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
> ```

You should define your relationships like this:

**Employee.php**

```php
// a Manager has many employees
public function employees(){
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'supervisor'); 
}

// an Employee works for a Manager
public function manager(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'supervisor');
}
```

Then in your controller:

**app/Http/Controllers/SomeCoolController.php**

```php
$employees_with_manager = Employee::with('manager')->get();

return view('employee/index')->with('employees', $employees_with_manager);
```

So in your view doing this will be enough:

**employee/index.blade.php**

```html
@foreach ($employees as $employee)
    <td>
       {{ $employee->manager->name }}
    </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for this, and your assumption is right, but that didn't work

Comment: @AlexG that's weird. Does it throw any errors? I haven't tested my code but as I can see it there is nothing wrong.

Comment: This one worked like a charm!! The part that is confusing is, how are yoy lookping through "employees" where you only passed "$employees_with_manager" using 'with' 
Sorry i am just new to laravel

Comment: Glad to help. Didn't understand your question? Are you referring to how the view loop in the array or how does the relationship is loaded? So to give you a better answer

Comment: Also, you forgot a ':' in Employee.php  belongsTo, i went to edit it, but won't let me

Comment: Missed that typo! Thanks for the observation, I've already updated the answer.

Comment: in the line {return view('employee/index')->with('employees', $employees_with_manager);} you are only passing "$employees_with_manager", but in the HTML side, you are looping through "employees" ... where does the "$employees" in the HTML come from. i don't see an instance that you defined "$employees" in the code

Comment: Oh ok. As you can see the `with` method has two parameters, the first one is the variable that will be available in the view and the second one is the value that this variable will take. So there's is where I define `'employees'` that takes the value of the `$employee_with_manager` variable. [This method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views) can also accept an array of values (the key is the variable and the value the information that will carry). You can even "sugar it" in a more Laravel way doing: `->withEmployees($employees_with_manager)`

Answer (score 0):

Each employee has multiple managers so there is no such thing as `$employees->manager`

Try this:

```
$employees = Employee:: with ('manager')->get(); 
return view('employee/index')->with('employees', $employees);
```